# Read docker-compose environment variable from ASP.NET Core controller

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to dockerize an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API project and so I am going to transfer all configs from `appSettings.json` to docker-compose environment section. And then going to read them from environment section in a controller. How should do this?

I have tried to use `IConfiguration` and `Environment` in the controller, but I have just got `Null`.

My `Program.cs` is:

```
namespace Order.Api
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
    }
}
```

And the `StartUp.cs` is:

```
namespace Order.Api
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<OrderContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionString")));
                // options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
            
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c => { c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo {Title = "Order.Api", Version = "v1"}); });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Order.Api v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
    }
}
```

And the `docker-compose.override` is:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  Order.Api :
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
      - ConnectionString=${ESHOP_AZURE_ORDERING_DB:-Server=sqldata;Database=Order;User Id=sa;Password=Pass@word}
      - MyConfig=Active
    ports:
      - "5001:80"


  sqldata :
    environment:
      - SA_PASSWORD=Pass@word
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    ports:
      - "5433:1433"
    volumes:
      - order-sqldata:/var/opt/mssql



volumes:
  order-sqldata:
    external: false
```

Comment: `ASP.NET` automatically reads config from env vars, you just need to provide it with right names, please include more details to question, like your `docker-compose` (or docker commands) and `appsettings.json`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten I have added docker-compose.override file and going to read ConnectionString or MyConfig in the controller

Answer (score 12):

`ASP.NET Core` provides an ability to load configuration from different places:

- `appsettings.json`
- `appsetting.<EnvName>.json`
- environment variables
- user secrets
- command line arguments

You shouldn't worry about where the settings came from. It's the same from developer's perspective. You can imagine it as a bunch of layer (each next layer overrides a setting from previous one). For example. When your application starts it tries to default load settings from `appsettings.json`, then override it by settings from `appsetting.<EnvName>.json`, then from environment variables, etc.

So, when you try to override `ConnectionString` in environment variables, the first thing you need to check it `appsettings.json`. How is it defined there? Let's creates simplest configuration:

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "from config"
  },
  "MyConfig": {
    "Key": "from config"
  }
}
```

To read this connection in `Startup.cs`, you don't need to change anything. Use your `options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));`.

And to override it in environment variables you need to provide it with specific name: `ConnectionStrings__ConnectionString=<new_connection>`. It's pretty simple, you need to flatten your JSON configuration and use `__` (double underscore) as a separator.

For custom configuration (like `MyConfig`) you need to do a little bit more. You need to create options class, like:

```cs
public class MyConfigOption
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
}
```

and configure it in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.Configure<MyConfigOption>(Configuration.GetSection("MyConfig"));
```

and then you will be able to override it in environment variables `MyConfig__Key=value`.

To use it in your controller, you need to ask DI for this options:

```
public Controller(IOptions<MyConfigOption> options)
{
    this.options = options;
}
```

`options` will contain your configuration.

See [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more details.